# In a combined paging and segmentation system, is there still internal and external fragmentation? Or are both eliminated?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

I believe that internal fragmentation would not exist in a combined paging and segmentation system since the segment pages are placed in are dynamically sized. This addresses the internal fragmentation issue with stand-alone paging system. However, what is the case for external fragmentation?

Answer (score 1):

Let's redefine "external fragmentation" as "physical memory fragmentation". Paging solves this.

Let's redefine "internal fragmentation" as "virtual memory fragmentation". Segmentation solves this.

However; when you have both segmentation and paging there's also "linear memory fragmentation" in the middle.  This "neither external nor internal, linear memory fragmentation" is as bad as the "internal fragmentation" you would have had with paging alone; so you can say that segmentation solved none of the problems (and just shifted a problem somewhere slightly different).

Comment: Thnak you for your response. So what then is the benefit of combining segmentation and paging?

Comment: @YoJoe: There's only 3 things I've seen segmentation used for that I can consider "beneficial in theory". The first is backward compatibility with ancient stuff that used segmentation before paging existed (e.g. software intended for DOS and "Win16" running under a 32-bit OS like Windows 95). The second is "small address spaces" in L4 (to split a 4 GiB virtual address space into smaller separate virtual address spaces to avoid TLB flushes for synthetic "ping-pong" micro-benchmarks). 1/2

Comment: @YoJoe: The last is having a "segment per thing" model (with major changes to programming environment and language/compiler to support it) to catch a few more bugs than paging alone (but less than a managed language, and with much higher overhead than paging alone). Mostly; it's not beneficial at all, which is why nobody bothers (everyone just uses paging alone) and why it became impossible/unsupported for 64-bit 80x86. 2/2